# How to convert the following data into zoo/xts/tseries object to calculate maximum drawdown?

Tags: r, xts

How to convert the following data into zoo/xts/tseries object to calculate maximum drawdown by using the function Return.calculate and Maxdrawdown function?

Hello friends i have equity(eg CENTURYTEX,AAPL,RIL etc) specific eod prices for around 400 equities in a single csv.

I want to calculate maximum drawdown. To calculate returns i am trying

```
ret=by[ddr3csv[,4],ddr3csv[,2],
                   function(x)Return.calculate(x,method="simple")]
```

which is giving 'closure' is not subsettable' error.

Once returns are obtained finding maximum drawdown will be easy.I am searching for the error but not able to figure out much.

```
rownum     name     code       date    price    readings

86916 CENTURYTEX 500040 11/04/2011 364.60     2994

86917 CENTURYTEX 500040 13/04/2011 376.70     2994

86918 CENTURYTEX 500040 15/04/2011 370.90     2994

86919 CENTURYTEX 500040 18/04/2011 365.85     2994
```

Comment: If you various stock prices in single csv file, how are you going to calculate maximum drawdown?

Comment: Do you calculate the  maximum drawdown for each returns? You must add also that you use `PerformanceAnalytics package.

Comment: @agstudy Oh sorry i forgot ot add that i am using performance analytics package.

Comment: @geektrader yes sir i have around 400 equities in a single file and want to calculate drawdown for each of them. for each equity the records are ordered

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to change `[`  by `(`( , so

```
ret=by[ddr3csv[,4],ddr3csv[,2],
                   function(x)Return.calculate(x,method="simple")]
```

To

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
ret=by(ddr3csv[,4],ddr3csv[,2],FUN=
                   function(x)Return.calculate(x,method="simple"))
```

Without data , I can't do beter. I imagine that you put your prices in the long format and use colmun 2 of your csv to separate between different stocks.

**EDIT**

You need to :

- split your data by code
- create an xts object for each group
- Compute the drawdows components.

  ```
  ## I read the data 
  ddr3csv <- read.table(text = 'rownum     name     code       date    price    readings
                                86916 CENTURYTEX 500040 11/04/2011 364.60     2994
                                86917 CENTURYTEX 500040 13/04/2011 376.70     2994
                                86918 CENTURYTEX 500040 15/04/2011 370.90     2994
                                86919 CENTURYTEX 500040 18/04/2011 365.85     2994',head=T)
  ## I coerce to Date , because xts needs numeric values as index
  ddr3csv$date<- as.Date(dat$date,format='%d/%m/%Y')
  ## I keep only computational columns (avoid naming/memory problems)
  dat <- ddr3csv[,c('code','date','price')]
  library(plyr)
  ddply(dat,.(code), function(x){
            x.xts <- xts(x$price,x$date)
           unlist(findDrawdowns (Return.calculate(x.xts,method="simple")))
  })
  ```

here my result

```
    code return from trough to length peaktotrough recovery
    1 500040      0    1      1  4      4            1        3
```

Comment: yes sir column 2 or column 3 can be used to distinguish between equitiies. basically only column 3,4,5 are important where column 3 is used for distinguishing. I tried your solution but its giving Error in UseMethod("xtsAttributes<-") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtsAttributes<-' applied to an object of class "zoo".

Comment: It is anther problem. I can't help you without knowing what is ddr3csv object? is it the data.frame you show or other thing? can you please add to your question , the resulat of this : `dput(head(ddr3csv))` or at least `str(ddr3csv)`

Comment: str(ddr3csv) 
'data.frame':   1048575 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ name    : Factor w/ 374 levels "ABB","ABBOTINDIA",..: 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 260 ...
 $ code    : int  1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 ...
 $ date    : Factor w/ 1498 levels "01/01/2008","01/01/2009",..: 91 142 194 343 394 446 494 545 691 738 ...
 $ price   : num  14015 13872 13861 13652 13566 ...
 $ readings: int  1498 1498 1498 1498 1498 1498 1498 1498 1498 1498 ...

Comment: i obtained ddr3csv by  ddr3csv=read.csv("dd2.csv",header=T,sep="\t")

Comment: thanks a lot sir its working,i used maxDrawdown function in place of findDrawdowns

Comment: @user2110832 don(t forget to check the solution if your are stasified with this answer.